# Aligning img and span

Tags: html, css

Please check the below link :

http://example.com/1/23.php

Here I am trying to align the span text eg Messages and photos such that it should appear in the middle wrt the icon.

Any help will be highly useful

Below is the code :

```
<div style="padding-left:20px">
<img src="icons/trophy1.png" > <span style="display:inline-block;padding-   bottom:5px;"> Messages</span>
<br>
<img src="icons/trophy1.png" > <span style="display:inline-block;padding-bottom:5px">Photos</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you insert the code you are currently working with?

Comment: @RobinV. : I have upadted my question with my code

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by setting the icon as the background of the span and change the `line-height` to the height of your icon.

```
span.trophy {
    background: url(icons/trophy1.png) no-repeat 5px 3px;    
    height: 32px;
    text-indent: 30px;
    line-height: 32px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DIV element to achieve this.

You should use the CSS text-align property on the container.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="icons/trophy1.png" > 
    <span style="display:inline-block;padding-bottom:5px;"> Messages</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The text won't become vertically centered with the icon this way. Both image and span will become horizontally centered within the div-element